# Convert multiple .dta files to .txt

Tags: file, notepad++, file-type, file-conversion

I have 70,000+ .dta files in a folder that I want to convert to .txt files. None of the examples I found of converting from .dta to .csv worked because my file versions are too new (and I don't have STATA to downgrade these files).

I was able to convert a .dta file manually with Notepad++ by just saving it as a .txt file. The .dta files only had numerical values, so no information was lost during the conversion.

Obviously I cannot save-as each file manually (I have 70,000+). Is there any way I could do this in batches?

Comment: I don't follow at all. If you don't have Stata or some other program that reads .dta files, what's the point of doing anything at all to these files? In particular, giving them a different extension will solve nothing. I must be missing something basic.

Comment: If the question is just about renaming files then the Stata tag is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it seems you simply wish to rename the files from `*.dta` to `*.txt`. Assuming that all the files are in a single folder, paste the following code into a batch file, place the batch file into said folder, and run:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('DIR /B "*.dta"') DO RENAME "%%I" "%%~nI.txt"
```

If there are files in subdirectories, add the `/S` switch after `DIR /B`

Disclaimer: The `dta` files I opened in Notepad++ looked like gibberish.